react native:react- navigation params keep resetting to previous values after navigtation.reset
In my react native application, i am accessing routes params from deeplink
this is how I am setting params from the deep link
const linking:LinkingOptions={
prefix:[...],
config:[...],
  async getInitialURL(): Promise<any> {
     
      const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      if (url != null) {
        return url;
      }
    },
    subscribe(listener) {
      const onReceiveURL = ({ url }: { url: string }) => {
        listener(url);
      };

 
      Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);

      return () => {

        Linking.removeEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
      };
    },}

and I am access params from deeplink on home like this
  const route = useRoute<any>();
  const params = route.params || '';

and after handling deeplink i am setting these params to undefined using
 navigation.setParams({
      am: undefined,
      external: undefined,
    });

and routes params get set to undefiend
but as soon as i navigate to any other screens and reset my navigation to Home
using
 navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        {
          name: 'Home',
        },
      ],
    });

routes params contains the values that i got from the deep link istead of undefined
I am using
@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",

i tried to pass the param in navigation.reset instead of setParams, but it didn't worked
   navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        {
          name: 'Home',
          params: {
            am: undefined,
            external: undefined,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

it also didn't work as previous values got reflected after doing navigation.reset from any other screen.

Can you post how the deep link is setting the params? My guess is that is firing on each navigation and since the link doesn’t clear until you kill the app or manually clear it, you keep getting it in params.

@johnhaup I have updated the question, Please review it!

@johnhaup how can we manually clear the params from deep link, I used setParams.

Can you post the code that sets the deep links to params?

@johnhaup, I have updated my question, hope this helps in understanding the issue, Thank you
